# Issue with accessing callback data property

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, socket.io

This piece of JQuery code works as intended:

```
socket.on('message', function(data){
                    if(data.message.length > 0) {
                            var pathCoordinates = [];
                            for (var i = 0; i < data.message.length; i++){
                                var point = new google.maps.LatLng(data.message[i].Latitude, data.message[i].Longitude);
                                pathCoordinates.push(point);
                            }
                            createDialog(pathCoordinates, data);
                    }
                    else
                        console.log("There is a problem:", data);
                });
```

This, however, does not. It never calls `createDialog()` or outputs the error message:

```
var lastID;

socket.on('message', function (data) {
  if (data.message.length > 0) {
    if (data.message[0].ID != lastID) {
      var pathCoordinates = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < data.message.length; i++) {
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(data.message[i].Latitude, data.message[i].Longitude);
        pathCoordinates.push(point);
      }
      createDialog(pathCoordinates, data);
    } else
      continue;
  } else
    console.log("There is a problem:", data);
});
```

It has to do with the if statement I added, `if (data.message[0].ID != lastID)`. Any idea what is causing this to break? `data,message[0].ID` should have a value, just as `data.message[i].Latitude` does.

Comment: Console throwing out any errors?

Comment: Have you verified (e.g., via `console.log` output) that `lastID` and `data.message[0].ID` are what you expect?

Comment: Ah, yes. 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal continue statement '

Answer (score 0):

'Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal continue statement ' was the issue. I removed the continue and placed a log message there instead to notify no updates were discovered. The code now works fine. Thanks!